# How to delete the system variable or the user variable from environment variables

Tags: batch

We are using the setx command in the batch script to set an environment variable.
Is there any command that can be used in batch script that can delete the environment variable in User and System variables and then set the variable defined in the batch script.

Any help will be appreciated.

Best Regards

Vilas

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the variable to an empty string.

[image: Setting and Unsetting an Environment Variable]

It looks gone to me.

Comment: Windows doesn't have a specific function to delete an environment variable but none is needed. Setting it to an empty string serves the purpose and is the only supported way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For local environment variables, you may delete them by setting to empty with the
[SET command](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

For system variables, this is more complicated.
You may set them to empty using the
[SETX command](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html).
It does delete the variable, meaning that the variable will no longer appear
in the environment block for new processes, but it does leave an empty entry
behind in the registry, which is probably not a good thing.

To totally delete a system variable, use instead the
[REG command](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html),
like this:

```
reg delete HKCU\Environment /F /V varname
```